# Incorrect OpenGL winding

Tags: c++, opengl

When initializing OpenGL, I set the following:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
```

Then, I draw a triangle on screen. That's all I do, really. But OpenGL always uses the opposite winding type of what I specify using `glFrontFace`.

The triangle vertices are defined as follows:

```
static GLfloat TRIANGLE[] = {
   0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  // Point 1 on image
  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  // Point 2
   0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  // Point 3
};
```

You can see the results on following image:

[image]

What I would expect is that GL_CCW draws the triangle and CL_CW doesn't. But what happens is the opposite.

My perspective and view matrices are correct. What could cause this problem?

Comment: You say your matrices are correct, but please show them so we can know. Your matrices could simply be looking at the triangle from the other side.

Comment: Yes, was going to suggest the winding depends on whether you're looking down +Z or -Z.

Comment: `glCullFace(GL_BACK);`, as it is a back face cull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glCullFace` specifies which side gets **culled away**, not which side is drawn. So when your triangle is given in CCW order and you enable everything the way you do, front faces (CCW faces) are culled away and nothing is drawn.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I didn't get the concept right. :)